# UICollectionViewCell not showing all views inside it

Tags: uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently implementing a custom calendar. I'm using `JTAppleCalendar` Pod that basically, as far as I understand, uses UICollectionView to allow the programmer to customize the calendar as much as he wants. My problem is that 2 of 4 `Views` that im putting inside the `UICollectionViewCell` are not appearing for some reason. It looks like the cell it's limiting the number of elements inside it. All the 4 `Views` are identical, but 2 of them are not appearing. I searched about it but didn't found anything that could help me. I tried even to overlay them, but even when i do it, they do not appear, Its just like the cell is bypassing them. Some pictures that may help to illustrate the situation

[image: UICollectionView picture from storyboard]

[image: UICollectionViewCell picture from storyboard]

[image: Result of the UICollectionView picture from simulator]

The pictures show that he's just showing the views from the middle. I thought that the problem could be space, however, as I sad, I tried to overlay them to see what happen and nothing. I've already made basic setup, as connecting them to my custom class. My custom class code:

```
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class CustomCell: JTAppleCell {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedView : UIView!
public var cellDate : Date?

@IBOutlet weak var firstTrainingCircle: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTrainingCell: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdTrainingCell: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var fourthTrainingCell: UIView!

}
```

JTAppleCalendarCell Code: https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/blob/master/Sources/JTAppleCell.swift

The day label, the `View` that display when the cell is selected and the middle `Views` are appearing as they should, so, why the green and red views are ignored?
I really have no idea why, excuse me if It's a dumb question, but since Im trying to solve It since yesterday and could get It I ask to you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi maybe you can check the constraints of your views to make sure they are correct? Sometimes bad constraints will not cause your view to show properly

Comment: Actually, after a few days trying to discover what is happening, actually were the constraints. I rebuild them and actually worked.